# How to replace the 6th character in the 3rd column/field in a comma-separated file?

Tags: regex, awk, sed

Assume a file has following content:

```
Peter,HongKong,000001HongKong,000001,20150901
Mary,London,000001London,000001,20150901
```

Now I want to replace, e.g. the 6th character in the 3rd column/field to 2.

s.t.:

```
Peter,HongKong,000002HongKong,000001,20150901
Mary,London,000002London,000001,20150901
```

How can I pass this to awk/sed?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

an awkward awk one-liner:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '$3=substr($3,1,5)"2"substr($3,7)' file
```

IMO, awk works better with column separated data than sed. E.g., if your requirement is to change something in 45th column, sed can do it, however not so straightforward as awk.

Answer (score 0):

I like this kind of exercise:

Bash:

```
#                             v   v
sed -E 's/^([^,]*,[^,]*,.....)./\12/' <<.e
Peter,HongKong,000001HongKong,000001,20150901
Mary,London,000001London,000001,20150901
.e
```

Result:

```
Peter,HongKong,000002HongKong,000001,20150901
Mary,London,000002London,000001,20150901
```

The first "v" marks what you are searching for, the second "v" the replacement

Assumptions:

- Fields don't contain ","
- You always replace by 2, no matter what was there
- It's ok to replace `654321HongKong` by `654322HongKong`

Comment: the first `v` position should be `.` instead of `1`, since OP said `6th char` not saying always `1`

Answer (score 0):

You have a good awk answer, for comparison here a perl alternative, which is a bit more straightforward as perl supports `substr` as lvalues:

```
perl -F, -ane 'substr($F[2], 5, 1) = "2"; print join ",", @F'
```

Output:

```
Peter,HongKong,000002HongKong,000001,20150901
Mary,London,000002London,000001,20150901
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(([^,]*,){2}[^,]{5})[^,]/\12/' file
```

or alternatively:

```
sed 's/^\(\([^,]*,\)\{2\}[^,]\{5\}\)[^,]/\12/' file
```

or another way:

```
sed 's/[^,]*/\n&/3;s/\n\([^,]\{5\}\)[^,]/\12/' file
```